# What is difference between vector<int>arr and int arr[]

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

What is the difference between `vector<int> arr` and `int arr[]`, except that arrays have some functions from  file?

There're some differences between `int arr[]` or `vector<int> arr` and `array<int, size> are`, since `int arr[]` and `vector` are dynamic sized unlike array and others.

Comment: One is a vector, the other is an array. They're not the same thing.

Comment: `vector` is not relevant to C. So assume you are asking about C++ (they are different languages) and thus have removed the C tag for you.

Comment: `int arr[]` is fixed size - it determines the size from the thing it is initialized with and you can't change the size afterward. `std::array<int, size>` is also fixed size but doesn't decay to a pointer when passed to a function so you always know what size it is.  A `vector<int>` isn't fixed size - it will automatically get bigger as things are added, plus it doesn't decay to a pointer when passed to a function so you always know what size it is

Answer (score 0):

An *array* is a language feature, inherited from C into the C++ language.  It's of a fixed size, and that size must be known at compile time.  It stores a bunch of values (or objects) in a sequence within memory.  It provides some functionality- you can access the elements of the array using the bracket operator.  (ie. `int x = arr[4]` would give you the element at the 4th index.)

`std::vector` is provided by the Standard Template Library (STL).  It's a container, meaning it's an object that stores other values and objects.  It provides a lot of extra functionality over a simple array.  Most importantly, that it can grow as new objects are added or removed from it.  If the vector grows larger than the memory that backs its storage, internally it will reallocate memory and move the stored values to a larger piece of memory.

Note: vectors and arrays can be accessed through iterators, which is a common way to loop through all of the elements in a container.

Other algorithms exist for container, allowing for all kinds of manipulations, sorting, finding, etc.

Comment: Be careful on how you word the stuff around iterators. You can get iterators to standard C arrays that work with the "Standard Library" just as well. Iterators is the glue that allows you to connect containers with algorithms.

Comment: Note: The term STL is now sort of obsolete. They are just part of the "Standard Library". The term STL was the original term for the template part of the "Standard Library" when we were standardizing around 2003 but its not accurate anymore.

Comment: Agreed, while possible, I think that's limited a little by its practicality.  If you've got to have a container that behaves like a C-style array, and you need iterator-access. then allow `std::array` to fill the gap for you.